# Find the domain of convergence of the series $\sum ^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{n}{n+1}\left(\frac{2x+1}{x}\right)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Find the domain of convergence of the series

$$\sum ^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{n}{n+1}\left(\frac{2x+1}{x}\right)^n$$

**My idea**

suppose if choose $y=\frac{2x+1}{x}$ then $\sum ^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{n}{n+1}\left(\frac{2x+1}{x}\right)^n=\sum ^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{n}{n+1}y^n$ and it has  radius $1$ then how we processed for further

Comment: $|\frac{2x+1}{x}|<1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your idea is fine. Your series converges if and only if $x\in\left(-1,-\frac13\right)$. That's because$$\left\{x\in\mathbb R\,\middle|\,\left\lvert\frac{2x+1}x\right\rvert<1\right\}=\left(-1,-\frac13\right)$$and because$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty y^n\text{ converges}\iff\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac n{n+1}y^n\text{ converges,}$$by [Abel's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test).

Comment: .......how the last step comes

Comment: It is a particular case of [Abel's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test).

Answer (score 0):

Note that:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}=1$$
so we can say that:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}\left(\frac{2x+1}{x}\right)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{2x+1}{x}\right)^n$$
and we know that for a series to converge of this form we require:
$$\left|\frac{2x+1}{x}\right|<1$$
using algebra we can work out that the boundaries of this are $-1$ and $-\frac 13$. Now reapply this to the equation and we get that:
$$x\in\left(-1,-\frac 13\right)$$